# new Texture2D and Texture.SetData will work in most cases but it's causing things to hang

Tags: c#, multithreading, opengl, monogame

Is this a bug in monogame, or am if I'm doing something wrong?

When running in a task/thread. It will cause OpenGL to hang/freeze. (Works fine in DirectX). Though this doesn't happen all the time. We use similar code to create textures from raw image data in another part of the program. It works fine over there and it's also in a task/thread.

Task created by:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>
{
    Task.Run(() => Data.TryAdd(SectionName, Dataobj.Create(new Rectangle(0, 500, (int)Size.X, 124))))
}
```

Hangs on either `SetData` or `new Texture2D`. Tested by moving the new texture2d into main thread.

```
Texture2D localdot = new Texture2D(Memory.graphics.GraphicsDevice, 4, 4);
Color[] tmp = new Color[localdot.Height * localdot.Width];
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
tmp[i] = Color.White;
localdot.SetData(tmp);
```

Part where I am waiting for complete.

```
 if (!Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), 10000))
                throw new TimeoutException("Task took too long!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the textures and arrays, in the main thread, prior to spawning the other threads. The task(thread) should only set the data array(s), upon completion, you can call `SetData()` in the main thread.

The `Texture2D` constructor nor `SetData()` is threadsafe and *may* lead to race conditions; Since `Texture2D` is connected to `GraphicsDevice`.

The (DirectX-OpenGL) discrepancy is most likely due to the locking mechanisms in the SharpDX(DirectX) implementation, that does not happen in the OpenGL version.

Performance may be improved in the "DirectX" version by adopting the above strategy.